# How to pass a generated user ID into search URL for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that is changing the default search provider using the following code in the manifest file:

```
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
  "name": "Name",
  "keyword": "example",
  "search_url": "https://search.com/s?={searchTerms}",
  "favicon_url": "https://example.com/favicon.ico",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "default": true
   }
```

I plan to generate a unique user ID for each extension install. I would like this unique ID to be passed into the default search URL.

Like this:

```
"search_url": "https://search.com/s?={searchTerms}&user_id={userid}"
```

Is there anyway to do this or is this not possible?

Comment: You'll have to use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest and manually substitute/append the id. Might be a better idea to set a cookie.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you!